# django-socialregistration for facebook keeps asking for module facebookapps

Tags: django, facebook, django-authentication

I am trying to use [`django-socialregistration`](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) django-app to provide authentication for my website via Facebook.

I followed the [setup guide](http://django-socialregistration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) and installed the dependencies:

```
$ yolk -l | grep "oauth2\|python-openid\|facebook-sdk\|django-socialregistration"
django-socialregistration - 0.5.4        - active 
facebook-sdk    - 0.3.0        - active development (/home/***/.virtualenvs/***/src/facebooksdk)
oauth2          - 1.5.211      - active 
python-openid   - 2.2.5        - active
```

**settings.py**

```
#...
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '*******'
FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY = '********'
FACEBOOK_REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = '********'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #...

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'socialregistration',
    'socialregistration.contrib.facebook'
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'socialregistration.contrib.facebook.auth.FacebookAuth',
)
```

But... When I run `manage.py syncdb` or `manage.py runserver` I get the following error:

```
Error: No module named facebookapps.utils
```

But there is no reference to `facebookapps` in any part of the plain-code. Even `django-socialregistration` does not possess any reference, from what I could verify.

The strange thing is the `settings.pyc`. When I grep for `facebookapps`:

```
$ grep -R "facebookapps" .
Binary file ./settings.pyc matches
```

I've already deleted this file over and over but it continues to be generated with this reference.

I am using Django 1.4.

Comment: What if your `settings.py` file constructs the `facebookapps.utils` string by accident? For example, are the strings `facebook` and `apps.utils` defined next to each other in `INSTALLED_APPS`, with the comma between them accidentally skipped? (Python concatenates strings that are adjacent, like `"hello " "world"`). Alternatively, could that mistake be made in one of the apps you use?

Comment: I'm embarrassed. The problem was just that. This is what happens when you work on weekends. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added this comment as a question so that you can accept it (so that the question will be marked as answered)

Comment: Thanks! (I dont like adding answers where I'm not sure whether it's the problem, like here where it is hypothetical, but perhaps I should get into the habit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your settings.py file constructs the facebookapps.utils string by accident? For example, are the strings facebook and apps.utils defined next to each other in INSTALLED_APPS, with the comma between them accidentally skipped? (Python concatenates strings that are adjacent, like "hello " "world"). Alternatively, could that mistake be made in one of the apps you use?